# Can we extend the definitions of words, and why?

Tags: meaning

The definition of read is as follow: To have a specified character or quality for the reader. This is when we say a "book reads like a philosophy book", but can we extend the meaning of that word to non-books? Look at the example below.

For example:

> Your thoughts read like a philosophy book for telepaths who delve
>   inside of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context that works. Telepaths "read" minds so references to books makes sense as a metaphor.

Comment: more generally most places where "read" is used idiomatically, the referenced definition of **read** could be used. "His apology read as insincere", "The party read as one of superficial friends trying too hard", etc.